# Telegram.Bot - отправка файла

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

У меня есть код:

```cs
                if (message.Text.Contains("file"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var id = message.Text.Split('_')[1];

                        if (fileIds.Contains(id))
                            SendFile(int.Parse(id), message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

- Задача этого кода, что когда юзер открывает ссылку типа *t.me/fileshare_robot?start=file_**204***, в переменную `id` записывалось число **204**. Ну а потом вызывалась функция SendFile():

```cs
       public static void SendFile(int id, Message msg)
       {
           var trueId = fileIds[id];
           Console.WriteLine($"Sending file with id {trueId}");

           InputOnlineFile inputOnlineFile = new(trueId);
           bot.SendDocumentAsync(msg.Chat.Id, inputOnlineFile, LangRu.sendedMsg);
       }
```

- Тут задача прислать юзеру файл под выбранным индексом.

Проблема в том, что в методе SendFile программа намертво зависает, точнее сказать не могу, где именно.

Я уже пробовал присылать просто локальный файл, но даже так, программа тоже зависает...

Полный проект: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/RMCM9ObxnAtDWw

```
        private static async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (update.Message is Message message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved " + message.Text);
                switch (message.Text)
                {
                    case "/start": Start(message); break;
                    case "/load": Load(message); break;
                }

                if (message.Document != null)
                {
                    var attachement = message.Document;
                    CreateFIle(attachement, message);
                }

                if (message.Text.Contains("file"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var id = message.Text.Split('_')[1];

                        if (fileIds.Contains(id))
                            SendFile(int.Parse(id), message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SendFile(int id, Message msg)
        {
            var trueId = fileIds[id];
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending file: {trueId}");

            InputOnlineFile inputOnlineFile = new("E:\\ssh-usernames.txt");
            bot.SendDocumentAsync(msg.Chat.Id, inputOnlineFile, LangRu.sendedMsg, allowSendingWithoutReply: true);
        }
```

Comment: `SendDocumentAsync` же асинхронный метод? Покажите его сигнатуру. Похоже на дедлок, нужно больше кода, откуда всё это вызывается тело вызывающего метода целиком. Если это из обработчика событий вызывается, новесь код от обработчика и вглубь до зависающего метода.

Comment: Как минимум, вы не понимаете, что такое `async/await`, делая SendDocument**Async** без `await`, да еще и в простом `void` методе.

Comment: нуу, я же не говорил, что профи

Comment: Тем более, там не было синхронного метода.